# Search input using literals to float

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm using this example

```
if (is_new_day)
    if (was_selected_day)
        //---------------------------------------------------- Calculation
        selected_day_high := temp_daily_high + (hMax/10)
        selected_day_low := temp_daily_low - (lMin/10)
        //---------------------------------------------------- Calculation
```

and I see the formula in the input box like below

```
cus = input("v1", options=[V1, V2])
V1 = '2'
V2 = '/10'
```

but I'm having a problem using it.

I get an error, pine script expects a number in the calculation lines but it working as is. Using str.tonumber hasn't worked for me. code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78109711/lines-from-a-date-picker/78110741#78110741)

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to use the `V1` and `V2` variables?

Comment: I tried float calc = na if/else

Comment: But where exactly are you using these variables? The code you linked to doesn't have any of these variables, so unless you post the code with any changes you have made, it will not be possible to assist you.